# Not able to pass prop in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to pass a simple prop from my `App.js` called `myname` to a component which handles all the navigations `TabComp` and trying to render it to one of the screens.

App.js

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
 render() {
   return(
    <TabComp 
      myname="bobby"/>
       )
     }
  }
```

TabComp

```
 const FavoritePage = () => (
  <View>
     <FavoriteComponent myname={this.props.myname} />
  </View>
  )

 const DetailsPage = () => (
  <View>
   <DetailsComponent />
  </View>
  )

 export const TabComp = TabNavigator({
   FavPage: {
      screen: FavoritePage,
             }
    DetailsPage: {
      screen: DetailsPage,
              }
       })
```

As soon as I do `<FavoriteComponent myname={this.props.myname} />` I get an error `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.myname')`.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's a stateless function and not a class, you don't use `this`:

```
 const FavoritePage = props => (
  <View>
     <FavoriteComponent myname={props.myname} />
  </View>
  )
```

Comment: Thank you, @matt-aft I am trying the code and attempting to render the prop by doing `const Favoritepage = props => ( <View><Text>{props.myname}</Text></View>)` but it doesnt render anything.

Answer (score 1):

use screenProps to pass params,like

```
<TabComp 
  screenProps={{myname:"bobby"}}/>
```

then in FavoritePage

```
const FavoritePage = () => (
    <View>
       <FavoriteComponent myname={this.props.screenProps.myname} />
    </View>
 )
```

and the same in DetailsPage

here is the [doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/tab#Navigator-Props)

Comment: Thank you. I just had to remove `this` from <FavoriteComponent line as pointed by @matt. and it works. you guys are awesome